# Patch to support multiple versions of app

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, dll

I have written a vb.net Windows forms application that, basically, lets a user load data from several sources onto a grid, perform mathematical and logical operations on the rows and columns, and then export the result.

Some users are asking for functionality that only they need, which I am happy to provide. However, this leads to multiple versions of the application and all sorts of maintenance issues.

I would like to solve this problem by making a standard version of the application, being able to send users asking for custom functionality some sort of patch to upgrade their version. My first thought is to put the parts of the code that needs to be dynamic in a .dll and to provide some sort of interface to change the dll-version from within the application itself. Would that be possible? Or should I turn to some installer-software to accomplish this?

I am not looking for a recipe here, just a nudge in the right direction to get me started. Any suggestion or warning is welcome!

Comment: Why not create a standard version with all the features, and just disable some features in the versions that don't require them? It simplifies maintenance and updates, but it will most likely be at the cost of file size

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it tends to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. Currently this has not been done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create an add-in architecture. You have to create at least three assemblies, i.e. projects in Visual Studio. Of course you need the main winforms application as executable file.

Then you need a class library declaring interfaces. These interfaces must define what an add-in can do. I can only give you a very rough impression, as the specific details heavily depends on what the add-ins must do. You could have a very basic add-in definition which goes like this:

```
Public Interface IAddIn
    ReadOnly Property Name As String
    ReadOnly Property Version As String
End Interface
```

Of course, such an add-in cannot do a lot, but it allows the executable to identify a class as add-in and to list its name an version in an about-dialog. You can add additional functionality directly to this interface, or you can create different interfaces for different types of add-ins. E.g. If an add-in wants to add its own menu items to the existing menu, you could let it implement this interface (in addition to `IAddIn`):

```
Public Interface IMenuItemProvider
    ReadOnly Property MenuItems As IEnumerable(Of ToolStripMenuItem)
End Interface
```

You can define mathematical functions or whatever you need.

Then you can create a class library project with an add-in class. Both the main executable and the add-ins must reference the project with the interfaces. This creates a bound between the executable and the add-ins.

The executable needs some code to load the add-ins. I've put this code into a class. (I have translated it from C# to VB without testing):

```
Public Class AddInLoader
    Public Function Load(ByVal folder As String) As IList(Of IAddIn)
        Dim addIns = New List(Of IAddIn)()
        Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.dll")

        For Each file As String In files
            addIns.AddRange(LoadFromAssembly(file))
        Next

        Return addIns
    End Function

    Private Shared Iterator Function LoadFromAssembly(ByVal fileName As String) As IEnumerable(Of IAddIn)
        Dim asm As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fileName)
        Dim addInInterfaceName As String = GetType(IAddIn).FullName

        For Each type As Type In asm.GetExportedTypes()
            Dim interfaceType As Type = type.GetInterface(addInInterfaceName)

            If interfaceType IsNot Nothing AndAlso (type.Attributes And TypeAttributes.Abstract) <> TypeAttributes.Abstract Then
                Dim addIn As IAddIn = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(type), IAddIn)
                Yield addIn
            End If
        Next
    End Function
End Class
```

Using this class, you can load the add-ins like this

```
Dim loader = New AddInLoader()
Dim addIns As IList(Of IAddIn) = loader.Load(myAddInFolder)

For Each addIn As IAddIn In addIns
    Dim menuProvider = TryCast(addIn, IMenuItemProvider)

    If menuProvider IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each menuItem As ToolStripMenuItem In menuProvider.MenuItems
            //TODO: Add menu item to application menu
        Next
    End If
Next
```